# XPath to text after inline label?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I am trying to get the xpath based on the account number "77-3456-07890123":

```
<div>
            <input name="personalisedAccountLister:accountRepeater:_ctl0:accountNumberField" type="hidden" id="personalisedAccountLister_accountRepeater_accountNumberField_0" value="7916921" style="">
            <b style="">Name:</b>
            Mr and Mrs Jones<br>
            <b style="">Account Number:</b>
            77-3456-07890123
        </div>
```

I've tried below but this returns nothing

```
//b[contains(text(),'77-3456-07890123')]
```

Strangely this also returns nothing

```
//*[contains(text(),'77-3456-07890123')]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming well-formed input,

```
<div>
    <input name="personalisedAccountLister:accountRepeater:_ctl0:accountNumberField"
           type="hidden" 
           id="personalisedAccountLister_accountRepeater_accountNumberField_0"
           value="7916921" style=""/>
    <b style="">Name:</b>
    Mr and Mrs Jones<br/>
    <b style="">Account Number:</b>
    77-3456-07890123
</div>
```

This XPath,

```
normalize-space(//b[.="Account Number:"]/following-sibling::text()[1])
```

will return the space-normalized string value of the first text node following the bold `"Account Number:"` label,

```
77-3456-07890123
```

as requested.